# Magento Feed Extensions

Tags: product, extensions, importexport

I have a client how is looking for an import extension, as he has about 6 or 7 feeds a day from different suppliers with different and same products.

These he uploads into his current website, or may even be automated feeds!!

Anyway, is there a 'feed import' extension for magento? as I have found alot of export to third party selling platforms, but nothing importing product feeds from wholesalers.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Well the devil is in the detail - it all depends on what you are looking for from a business perspective - there are three key types. 1) you can program scripts; 2) you can use a tool like Magmi; 3) use onboading tools.

The first is obvious, you need to maintain code and the business manager cannot make changes. The second is not via programming but more ideal for data loads - data maintenance is a problem due to the reindexing as they are direct db inserts. The third, onboarding tools, these are business friendly that do not require any programming to make changes, clean the data before loading, and only perform deltas (changed records) to reduce overhead - however there are very few of them and even less that work with Magento.

So the question is, which type do you need. By the way, this is business discussion not a technical one in case the post gets flagged for being irrelevant (not to us but that is another matter).

Answer (score 0):

uRapidFlow -- can setup automatic product / category imports.

Comment: put some more info in your answer